# Multiple model binding and dubugging data for each binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have three view model bindings attached to a single page using the following syntax:

```
ko.applyBindings(new SomeViewModel(), document.getElementById("some-id-element"));
```

I would like to do a data dump to watch the model states as I test the page. Before I went the multiple model route I was using the following to review the page model data at the bottom of my page.

```
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></pre>
```

Naturally, now that the $root context has been moved in to specific elements nothing is returned using just $root. I'm having a hard time understanding how I can target each separate view model so I can see each view's specific data.

I've tried assigning a new model as a global variable

```
testVar = new SomeViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(testVar, document.getElementById("some-id-element"));
```

And used the following examples:

```
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(testVar, null, 2)"></pre>
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(testVar.$root, null, 2)"></pre>
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($element.some-id-element, null, 2)"></pre>
```

Nothing is returned in any of these tests

As I clearly do not understand the scoping here, I hope someone can educate me as to what I am missing.

thank you,

Cary.

*edited for spelling.

Comment: Spelling error: `testVav`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind the debug field to the composition of the view-models:

```
ko.applyBindings({vm1: vm1, vm2: vm2, vm3: vm3},
    document.getElementById("debug"));
```

```html
<div id="debug">
    <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(vm1, null, 2)"></pre>
    <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(vm2, null, 2)"></pre>
    <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(vm3, null, 2)"></pre>
</div>
```

​
http://jsfiddle.net/MizardX/jxM9f/

Alternatively, you should be able to access global variables. (Assuming they really are global variables)

http://jsfiddle.net/MizardX/2Y6DF/

Comment: Nice, Thank you for this. In the meantime I was targeting my debugging output by essentially reference a global variable of the model like so: `<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(randomViewModel.BINDING)"></pre>`. I had them all over the page though ;). This will help greatly. I also found this bookmarklet that helps to poke around the various elements and their data structures. [bowtie](http://bowtie-ko.com/)

Cheers, c

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to create helper function that handles the ko.toJSON method. Then I place a ko.computed on my viewmodel that call the helper. This way I can bind the ko.computed on the viewmodel to the View and display it. If I have multiple viewmodels bound to a single view I can show one per viewmodel on the same page using a standard binding.

```
<pre data-bind="text: debugInfo"></pre>
```

Comment: Great idea, I will have to give that a try. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Syntax is

```
<div data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root)"></div>​
```

See example at http://jsfiddle.net/photo_tom/eY9w8/9/.  If you click on any of the columns, you can see the output change.

Comment: `ko.toJSON` passes any extra arguments to `JSON.stringify`. In this case, `ko.toJSON(x, null, 2)` will make it indent the JSON with 2 spaces. Without it, it will just be one long line.

Comment: Ah, that's awesome. I kept seeing the reference to (x, null, 2) but I had yet to get that far in. Thank you for the tip.